# Cannot read resource from Jar File

Tags: java, jar

I am having trouble figuring out this problem and I have tried almost everything.

I would like my program to read two resources from Jar File, and it will run fine through eclipse. However it gives nullpointer exception when I run the jar from command prompt.

Structure:

> src/main/java/App.java
>
> src/main/resources/properties/application.properties
>
> src/main/resources/spring/applicationContext.xml

Code:

To read application.properties

> properties.load(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/properties/application.properties"));

To read applicationContext.xml

> context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/applicationContext.xml");

Error:

> Error while loading
> application.properties java.lang.NullPointerException

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in your structure you show where the .java is, but you´re missing the .class. The path where it resides is the one the classloader will use. There should be your resources

EDIT: to clarify a bit. In your post you mention the path to App.java. but the classloader only cares about App.class, so let´s say you have

```
\src
 |...(App.java and whatever, these will be ignored)
\bin
 |
 |--App.class
 |
\bin\resources\...(properties and whatever, these will be read)
```

you should make sure you have properties and spring directories under bin. 
If you only have the .java in src it will be ignored by the classloader.

Comment: are you saying that I should move the resource to where App.java is? Could you also explain where I am missing ".class"?

Comment: oooh ok this makes sense, however I notice my eclipse did not create the bin folder at all for this project. Is it because I am using maven?

Comment: the name "bin" is just an example, you should use the directory name where your .class resides. btw eclipse by default hides the destination path, so probably you do have a "bin" folder, or "classes" or whatever ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these are in a jar file that is available on the classpath at runtime, the first, `getResourceAsStream()` example is probably failing because you haven't specified the full path within the jar file.  (Also, a common failure it to leave off the leading /, but you seem okay there.)  E.g.:

```
properties.load(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/properties/application.properties"));
```

However, if you are unsure where (what path) the files have been given in the jar file that was built, try

```
jar -tvf <your-jar>.jar
```

to see what is actually in it.

Can't comment on `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`; not a Spring developer.

Comment: Ok I tried 

**properties.load(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/properties/application.properties"));**

and even tried it without the leading /, but I got the same error.

When I try to run 

**java -tvf eligibilityloader-1.0.jar**

I get 

**Unrecognized option: -tvf
Could not create the Java virtual machine.**

Comment: oh yes sorry my bad, just tried **jar -tvf eligibilityloader-1.0.jar** and got 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I should run it through command prompt right?

Comment: Yes.  Is the jdk/bin directory on your PATH?

Comment: ok I set the Path environment variable, and it ran. However I don't see the path to the resources. Are they suppose to be in the list?

Comment: If they are not in the .jar file (or one of the .jar files that make up your application, if more than one) *and* aren't elsewhere on your CLASSPATH (if it includes other things, like directories of classes) *then* `getResourceAsStream()` is not going to find them.  It looks like your build process isn't picking up and including the files from your resources directory.  How are you building?  Ant?  Maven?  Something else?

Comment: ok well I am trying to build it with maven, however it is saying that it cannot find main class :(. So what I tried to do instead was to export it as a runnable jar with eclipse, and run it through command prompt that way. It does run but it would say it cannot find application.properties